# List item add with event receiver COMException

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, updatelistitems, splongoperation

I expose my scenario and my issue.

**Scenario**

I have one `custom list` in SharePoint 2010 Foundation called **Actions**. This list has one event receiver that override this methods:

- ItemAdded
- *ItemUpdated*
- *ItemCanceled*

Inside the method `ItemAdded` I perform these actions:

- Update column's item
- Update item's roles
- Add items inside other lists

Now, inside my SiteCollection there is another Event Receiver of list **Projects** that when one item is added perform these actions:

1. Read data from one list called *Task Template*
2. Copy retrieved data inside Task list.

**Issue**

When I add one item inside **Projects** list code of ItemAdded of **Actions** list raise one `COMException`. Below is some more info about exception:

> Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes. 
>   Stacktrace: 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, ...

**Inner Exception**

> Exception type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 
>   Message       : Save Conflict.
>
> Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want >your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, >and resubmit your >changes.0x81020015 
>   Stacktrace: at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String

Debugging my application I discovered that exception above is raised when I try to perform this action:

```
item.Update();
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the ItemAdded event as Synchronous event.

You can define it programmatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverdefinition.synchronization.aspx

Or in the Receiver element of the feature definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512765.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b97c8cb0-fc95-4a2e-8af7-d156e91a8692/save-conflict-while-updating-splistitem-for-document-library